# express js can't redirect user

Tags: node.js, express, monodevelop

```
var express = require('express');
var firebase = require('firebase');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var router = express.Router();




    router.post('/api/login', function(req, res) {

      var email = req.body.email;
      var pass = req.body.password;


                login(email, pass);




    });


     function login(email, pass){
        firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE);
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(function (user) {
          if(user){
            console.log('user');
            res.redirect('/signup');
          };




        }).then(() => {
          // A page redirect would suffice as the persistence is set to NONE.
          return firebase.auth().signOut();
        }).then(() => {
          window.location.assign('/signup');
        }).catch(function (error) {

          var errorMessage = error.message;
        });  // auth catch End 

      };// login fun
```

............................................................................................................................................................
**if user not equal to null then i want to redirect user to signup**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the POST request is coming from an Ajax call in a browser web page, then the response to the request goes only to your script that made the Ajax call.  The browser does not see it at all, thus the browser does nothing itself with the response to the POST.  The response just goes to your script.  So, if you want the page to redirect after an Ajax call, then you need to return a response that the script can identify and the script then needs to do a client-side redirect such as:

```
window.location = "http://someURL";
```

In cases where your script is looking for a redirect response, you can either have the script look at the status and header to see the redirect or you can, instead just return some JSON that tells the script what to do.

---

If the POST request comes from an HTML form in the browser (without Javascript involved), then the browser will look at the response from the POST and either display the resulting response (if it's a 2xxx response) or follow the redirect if it's a 3xx response.